# (Can I minimize the) Footprint of template in my C++ Code?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a large class which basically handles one buffer of variable (numeric) datatype. So it seems a good choice to use a class template with this datatype as the only parameter. I'm not experienced in C++ and I wonder/worry a bit about the "footprint" such a template makes in my code.

There are three implications of templates which in my (C++ unexperienced) eyes are not necessary and make code ugly. I tried to avoid them, but neither did I find a good example how to do it nor did I manage to find it out by myself.

So the goal of this question is: Can you either confirm the following statements or give a counterexample?

1. When using a class template, all class methods have to go into the header file. Even if they have no templated type in their interface or implementation.
2. When using a static method or member of the class, I always have to specify a template parameter (`MyClass< double > :: MY_STATIC`), even if the templatization does not affect any of the static properties of the class.
3. When using the class as a parameter for a function, I always have to give a template parameter, even when this function does not access any of the templated members? (`function myFunc(MyClass< double> & myClass){ do something }` )

Comment: It seems that all of your problems can be solved by using a base class which should contain necessary non-templated members and methods (including static ones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, don't have functions/data members in a template class which does not use the template parameters. Have a base class, put all non-template related things there, your template class should derive from it.

To answer your questions:

- yes, everywhere where you need to instantiate the template, you need to see the full definition of the class and it's functions
- yep, but put that into the base class
- yes, see above

EDIT: One of the reasons to move to base class is code bloating (this expression actually exist, you can google it for more info): If you don't move the template unrelated code to a base class, the very same template independent code will be copied for all instantiation of your template, which means a lot of unnecessary code. If you put it to a base class, you will only have this code once.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. On the plus side, the code is only generated when the metod is actually used for the specialization.
2. Yes. However, there is no (other then design choice) need for a static method to be a memeber of the templated class if it has no use for the templated parameter.
3. Yes. The size and memory layout of the structure is determined by the template parameter.